# SQL Arithmetic Invalid Number

Tags: sql, oracle, math

This will probably be extremely simple, but I haven't been able to find the solution myself.

I just want to perform this operation as part of a query

```
1 - (RELEASE_QUAN/TOTAL_QTY_ORD)
```

Which gives me the error(And I'm very certain this is what's causing it)

> ORA-01722: invalid number

And this works fine

```
(RELEASE_QUAN/TOTAL_QTY_ORD)
```

Why can't I do the first line?

#

The full query

```
SELECT

REQUEST_DATE,
Company,
CUSTNO,
MISC_ITEM || '-' || CUSER1,
V_RELEASES_COMB_ACCT_LINK.EXTENDED_PRICE * ((RELEASE_QUAN/TOTAL_QTY_ORD)) ||  1 - (RELEASE_QUAN/TOTAL_QTY_ORD) 


FROM
IQMS.V_RELEASES_COMB_ACCT_LINK V_RELEASES_COMB_ACCT_LINK

INNER JOIN
 IQMS.V_GLACCT V_GLACCT
ON
 V_RELEASES_COMB_ACCT_LINK.GLACCT_ID = V_GLACCT.ID
```

Comment: I don't see how subtracting a valid expression from "1" could result in that error.

Comment: Could you share the full query? This expression should not produce an ORA-01722.

Comment: I'll add the full query now, but yeah. I don't think it should be but it's what seems to atm

Comment: Are the values for `RELEASE_QUAN` and `TOTAL_QTY_ORD` valid numbers? And TOTAL_QTY_ORD isn't NULL?

Comment: It's ok now. It simply needed brackets surrounding it. I just didn't think of them in the first place

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing string concatenation with multiplication.

In the expression

```
V_RELEASES_COMB_ACCT_LINK.EXTENDED_PRICE * ((RELEASE_QUAN/TOTAL_QTY_ORD)) ||  1 - (RELEASE_QUAN/TOTAL_QTY_ORD)
```

It appears as the expression is being evaluated as

```
(V_RELEASES_COMB_ACCT_LINK.EXTENDED_PRICE * ((RELEASE_QUAN/TOTAL_QTY_ORD)) || 1) - (RELEASE_QUAN/TOTAL_QTY_ORD)
```

Comment: Much better answer than that of the OP: this gives at least an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a real simple solution as I thought. I was just too slow to think of it

I surrounded the expression with brackets

```
(1 - (RELEASE_QUAN/TOTAL_QTY_ORD))
```

It works now.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is still very poor coding. If you want the numeric result of the calculation to be concatenated within a longer string, you should wrap the numeric result within the `TO_CHAR()` function, to make it explicit that you want the result considered as a string and not a number. Then, for example, if the result is 0.9207923048 but you want to concatenate just 0.92, you can easily do that: `TO_CHAR( 1 - .... , '0.99')`, etc.